# bootstrap-datetimepicker didn't work

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, web

I am using twitter bootstrap v3.1.
calendar option is not display.

```
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class='well'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss'
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include [moment.js](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/scripts/moment-2.4.0.js) above your datetimepicker.js and below bootstrap.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/scripts/moment-2.4.0.js"></script>
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lyhkn/).